# How to enable side scrolling for Apple A1152 mouse in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mouse, scrolling, mouse-scroll

I've got an old Apple A1152 mouse with a scroll ball on top that I'm using with Ubuntu 22.04.  It scrolls up and down happily, but won't scroll left to right.  I've found posts about how to enable horizontal scrolling in older versions of Ubuntu, but nothing about how to do it in 22.04.  If it is still possible, could anyone give me instructions on how to get my mouse fully functional?

Here's the output of `xinput`:

```
aschamberlain@aschamberlain-desktop:~$ xinput

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Mitsumi Electric Apple Extended USB Keyboard  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ UVC Camera (046d:0825)                    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Mitsumi Electric Apple Extended USB Keyboard  id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Mitsumi Electric Apple Extended USB Keyboard System Control   id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Mitsumi Electric Apple Extended USB Keyboard Consumer Control id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

And here's the output of xinput list-props 13:

aschamberlain@aschamberlain-desktop:~$ xinput list-props 13

```
Device 'Mitsumi Electric Apple Extended USB Keyboard':
    Device Enabled (156):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (158): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (293):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (294):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (295):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (296):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (297):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (298): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (299): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled (300):    0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Lock Enabled Default (301):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (302):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (303):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (304): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (305): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (306):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (307):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (308):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (309): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (310): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (278): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (279):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (280):    0, 0
    Device Node (281):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Device Product ID (282):    1452, 523
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (311):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (312):   1
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (313):    15
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (314):    15
    libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (315):    1
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` command.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I've added the results from xinput above

Comment: Now please add output of `xinput list-props 13`

Comment: Done!  I see there's a horizontal scroll enabled line that's set to 1.  Is there anything else in there that could prevent the horizontal scrolling from working?